# How to add command line tool to python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have written a simple package called fcards that is currently on PyPI. The package provides a curses based interface for creating and practicing flash cards, and right now, in order to run it, the user must type "python -m fcards.fcards". I would like to know how to make it so the user can simply type "fcards" to run the application.

I've tried using the "scripts" and "entry_points" arguments in the setup function in my setup.py file but so far nothing has worked consistently on all platforms.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux

Comment: in case for windows, you could make it a `.bat` file that runs your command. They'll have to run `fcards.bat` though

Comment: _so far nothing has worked consistently on all platforms._ What did not work when you added an entry point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, I write a console driver and put it in a file `console.py` as the `main` function.

Then in `setup.py`:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['<name> = <name>.console:main'],
},
```

where `<name>` is the name of the module. This has worked out-of-the-box on UNIX-like platforms. It also worked using the Anaconda Python distribution on ms-windows.

On ms-windows the distinction between `console_scripts` and `gui_scripts` is *important*, because the latter have to be associated with another python binary. This is done by giving them the extension `pyw` instead of `py`. UNIX-like platforms (incuding macOS, I guess) generally don't care.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly (on linux and windows). I just wrapped the part of my code that sets up variables and feeds them to my main function in its own function and pointed the console scripts thing to that.